# Xamarin getting a wrong color from bitmap

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, bitmap, xamarin.android

I'm trying to make a color picker on android, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong that I'm getting a wrong colour. I have an ImageView, and I'm decoding this image to bitmap. In bitmap I'm using a `GetPixel()` method, but i think that I'm doing something wrong at this point. Can someone tell what I'm doing wrong? Here is the image that I'm using:

[image]

I'm testing it on Z1 Compact (720x1280 resolution, android 5.1.1), and picture is 750x300, so maybe the resolution is the problem?

```
 namespace ImageViewTest
    {
        [Activity(Label = "ImageView", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
        public class MainActivity : Activity
        {
            protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
            {
                base.OnCreate(bundle);

                int colorPickerWidth = 750, colorPickerHeight = 300, colorBaseHeight = 1184, colorBaseWidth = 720;
                float colorPickerScaleWidth = 720 / colorBaseWidth, colorPickerScaleHeight = 1184 / colorBaseHeight;

                // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
                RelativeLayout rl = FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(Resource.Id.relative);
                ImageView colorPanel = new ImageView(this);

                colorPanel.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.colorPicker);
                colorPanel.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(colorPickerWidth, colorPickerHeight);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(this.Resources, Resource.Drawable.colorPicker);
                bitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(bitmap);

                colorPanel.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
                colorPanel.Touch += (object sender, TouchEventArgs e) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("X:" + (int)e.Event.GetX());
                    Console.WriteLine("Y:" + (int)e.Event.GetY());
                    try
                    {
                        Color pixel = new Color(bitmap.GetPixel((int)e.Event.GetX(), (int)e.Event.GetY()));
                        int red = Color.GetRedComponent(pixel), green = Color.GetGreenComponent(pixel), blue = Color.GetBlueComponent(pixel);
                        Console.WriteLine("R:" + red + " G:" + green + " B:" + blue);
                    }
                    catch
                    {

                    }
                };

                rl.AddView(colorPanel);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which color do you expect and which color do you get? Please figures! Starting with X,Y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scale the touch X/Y coordinates based upon the size of the `ImageView` and your original drawable/bitmap (intrinsic values), offset the X/Y by the current bounds and that *should* give you the coordinates of the touch translated to your bitmap (unless you have applied some type of other translations or effects to your bitmap).

```
var drawable = (BitmapDrawable)colorPanel.Drawable;
colorPanel.Touch += (object sender, Android.Views.View.TouchEventArgs e) =>
{
    var intrinsicScaleX = (float)drawable.IntrinsicWidth / (float)drawable.Bounds.Width();
    var intrinsicScaleY = (float)drawable.IntrinsicHeight / (float)drawable.Bounds.Height();
    var viewScaleX = (float)drawable.IntrinsicWidth / (float)colorPanel.Width;
    var viewScaleY = (float)drawable.IntrinsicHeight / (float)colorPanel.Height;
    var x = (e.Event.GetX() - drawable.Bounds.Left) * intrinsicScaleX * viewScaleX;
    var y = (e.Event.GetY() - drawable.Bounds.Top) * intrinsicScaleY * viewScaleY;
    var pixel = drawable.Bitmap.GetPixel((int)x, (int)y);
    Console.WriteLine($"{viewScaleX}:{viewScaleY}::{e.Event.GetX()}:{e.Event.GetY()}:{x}:{y}:{Color.GetRedComponent(pixel)}:{Color.GetGreenComponent(pixel)}:{Color.GetBlueComponent(pixel)}");
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's works :) I had no idea that i have to also scale a "x, y" coordinate. I was pretty sure that it's related to image size.